# RoxyFileman blank pop up on server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce, roxy-fileman

I'm using Nopcommerce, everything seems to work fine on the local machine. But after publishing and uploading the site to the server when I want to insert an image or video an empty pop-up opens with only RoxyFileman title.
By browsing the pop's source I can see the controls are in the page but not displayed.
How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Provide read/write permission to image folder(yourwebsite\Content\Images) for local IIS user . Also do check & clear System Warning from website ->admin->System->Warning.

Better you provide screen shot of issue if still problem persist.